# Postgresql jsonb (Rails) - query multiple values, via an array, in a single json attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, postgresql-9.4

In Rails I can do `.where(:attr => [val1, val2, val3])` and I'll get back all the rows matching any of those `val1-3`.

I'm using Postgres/Postgresql and have a jsonb type and I'd like to do a similar thing. PsuedoCode: `.where("col @> ?", {attr: [val1, val2, val3]}.to_json)`, but this returns nothing - bc it's trying to find a value of the entire array `[val1, val2, val3 ]` not  each of the individual values: `val1`, `val2`, `val3`?

Is there any way to pass in multiple values, relative to as single attribute, in a jsonb query?

I could do `.where("attr @> {.. val1 ...} OR attr @> {... val2 ..} ...")`, but it seems like there would be a better way.

I've tried various things from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html, but seem to have a solution evading me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can often generalize OR expressions using [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20338):

> **9.23.3. ANY/SOME (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ANY (array expression)
> expression operator SOME (array expression)
> ```

So something like this:

```
where c = 1 or c = 2 or c = 3
```

can be written as:

```
where c = any(array[1,2,3])
```

The *operator* doesn't have to be `=` or course, it can be `>`, `like`, or even `@>`. Also, if the value of a placeholder is an array then ActiveRecord will expand that array as a comma-separated list in the SQL so things like:

```
where('c = any(array[?])', [1,2,3])
```

will become:

```
where c = any(array[1,2,3])
```

by the time the database sees it.

Combining the above with your JSON gives you something like:

```
where('attr @> any(array[?]::jsonb[])', [val1, val2, val3].map(&:to_json))
```

The `::jsonb[]` is a type cast to make sure PostgreSQL sees the array as an array of `jsonb` rather than an array of `text`.

Comment: Sweet! I'll test it today and get back to you!!

Comment: Works great! Thanks! `Model.where("model_attributes @> any(array[?]::jsonb[])", [{attr: 1}, {attr: 2}].map(&:to_json))`!!

Comment: any tips on how to apply this to a nested value? e.g. if my jsonb attr looks like `{"inner_key": "inner value"}`... It doesn't seem to work with `where("attr->>inner_key @> any(array[?]::jsonb[])")` ...

Comment: @gingerlime The `->>` operator gives you `text`, not `jsonb`. You'd want to use `->` to give you `jsonb` or a `text[]` instead of `jsonb[]`.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks a lot! I somehow went around in circles, and didn't spot this obvious thing...

Comment: @gingerlime The best place for a bug to hide is right out in the open where you'd never look for it ;)

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL, you may need to pass your values in as strings even if you're trying to match against an array of integers: `where("attr @> any(array['1', '2', '3']::jsonb[])")`